# Order of converting dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am converting a `dataframe` in python to `JSON` format and then sending this `JSON` on the frontend. For this conversion, I am using [to_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) function of `DataFrame`.
After performing some read operations on `JSON`, user provides location of  any particular row back to server. 
Can I be sure that while converting `DataFrame` to `JSON`, Python preserves the order of rows ? Elaborating further: can I assume that 100th row in `DataFrame` will correspond to 100th `JSONObject` in `JSONArray` generated ?

And if I can't, then what will be the best way to provide this information to the server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using something like primary key (immutable identifier) in the DataFrame's index and locate row by the value.